# Theme not working for Button

Tags: xpages

I started playing with themes.  I was able so create CSS and associated the CSS to various table elements.  Works fine.

Now I am trying to do the same with a button. But it does not seem to work.  If I apply the styleclass right to the button then it works.

```
<theme extends="oneuiv2.1"> 

<resource>
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>app.css</href>
</resource>

<resource>
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>viewpicklistCC.css</href>
</resource>


<control>
    <name>Button</name>
    <property>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>MyButton</value>
    </property>
</control>



<control>
    <name>HtmlTable</name>
    <property>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>PNCTable</value>
    </property>
</control>

<control>
    <name>HtmlTd</name>
    <property>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>PNCTableCell</value>
    </property>
</control>


</theme>


.MyButton {
width:179.0px;
font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:18pt;
color:rgb(255,128,0);
font-weight:bold
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a theme you need to use the theme id of a control in order to target it. This is not the same as the CSS style class.

You can set the theme id manually on a control (in Style - Theme, or in All properties - Style - Theme id) and then target the control by referring to this theme id.

Or you can use the default theme id for a control. The XPageswiki contains a list of default theme ids for core controls:
http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_themes#themeID+values+for+core+controls

So in your case you need to use one of the following theme ids in order to target your button:

```
Button: Button.Command
Button with type=submit: Button.Submit
Button with type=cancel: Button.Cancel
```

Comment: And use getComponent("ELEMENTID").getStyleKitFamily() to get the themeId of a component type. Note that some Extension Library components don't have a getStyleKitFamily() method.

Comment: Paul thanks for posting this. This was going to be the next question I was going to ask.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like that list might be incomplete but thanks to Paul you can fill in the pieces.  It would be nice to have this a part of designer, right click on the control and get it's theme id along with other important properties.

Comment: How do manually applied theme ids work?  Is that set under style?  Can I give say a theme id to my custom control then my user programmers can use that id in their own themes?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the answer theme ids are set under Style. You can set a theme id on a custom control but I have not tried to use that. But yes, that theme id can then be used by others that reuse that custom control.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I am on a roll.   But I hit a snag with InputField.EditBox.  It does not seem to work when I add it to my theme.  If I apply the css style direct to the control then it works.   I verfied the theme id really is InputField.EditBox  with the function that Paul posted.

Comment: Hit the a similar snag with Column.View.  What I am trying to do is set the text size and font.   I also tried Text.ViewColumn.

Comment: Bruce, what specificly are you trying to achieve with the theme for those two controls? I suggest you create a new question with some code snippets and theme snippets :-)

Comment: Yep will create another question.