# Benefits of using themes in XPages

Tags: xpages

[This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622480/theme-not-working-for-button) got me interested into Themes. But the example in the question just assigns a CSS class in theme file to a themeId which is in turn assigned to the element with respective themeId on XPage. I could also directly assign the class name to component in XPage.

So my first question is what benefit does a theme bring to an XPage?

I was trying to explore what other properties could be assigned via themes and it seems we can assign other properties like `valign` and `style` in the theme file like this:

```
<control>
    <name>HtmlTd</name>
    <property>
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>tdclass</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>style</name>
        <value>font-family: Courier</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>valign</name>
        <value>top</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

The above code actually sets the `valign` and `style` for all the `<td>` tags in XPage. So my second question is what all properties could be set via themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Themes are very powerful. Almost every control in XPages is [really a bean](http://avatar.red-pill.mobi/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-8GK6K7) meaning that you can set *almost* all of its properties using themes (see clarification of this in the answer from Paul).

Here some useful resources:

- Tim Tripcony has created a presentation called [Taking Themes to the Next Level](http://de.slideshare.net/dominion/taking-themes-to-the-next-level) which highlights some of the powerful features of themes.
- The XPageswiki.com has [a page on themes](http://xpageswiki.com/apps/wiki-xpages/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_themes)

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify Per's answer, you can set *almost* everything. That's because the theme gets applied during the Render Response phase.

You can't override properties on the XPage with SSJS set to run on page load. That's because a static value is set, so no runtime bindings get applied.

You can't set anything that needs to be known before Render Response, e.g. the var property of a repeat control.

Render Response phase is why it's better for performance. If you use SSJS to compute a value on an XPage, it gets calculated a number of times during the partial refresh. If it's in a theme, it's only calculated during Render Response.

To look at examples of themes in action, look at OpenNTF and look at dPloy project by Tim and XPages Help Application by me.

Comment: true, I should have said: meaning that you can set almost all of its properties using themes.Thanks, Paul