# Why should i use themes in my xpages application?

Tags: xpages

I have used themes and css. Themes seems to be a little bit to restrictive for me while css offers(beside the bigger user community) more posibilities for the layout.

Can someone explain to me the benefit of using themes. What do i gain that a centrally stored css cant do?

Comment: Themes control more than just layout (CSS)

Comment: Can you please give an example of something i couldnt do with css and js. I would like to know that.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12634640/785061

Comment: With Themes you can f.e. define page titles, favicons, meta tags, resources, javascript code, for a single application or even for all applications on a server at once. You don't need to change (rebuild) an existing application when changing a theme, they are processed on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

Besides what Frank and Paul mentioned, a theme can also be where you include any client side script or font libraries (i.e. jQuery, FontAwesome, etc) that will be needed on all the xpages. Define it once in the theme and everything else will get it.

You might also want to check out Tim Tripcony's slide deck for Taking themes to the next level.
http://www.slideshare.net/dominion/taking-themes-to-the-next-level

Tim's blog post why extensive use of Themes speeds up XPage execution:
http://timtripcony.com/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-8TDRFJ

Lastly, Tim's blog post determining the ThemeId of any component
http://timtripcony.com/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-8RXAQ6

Answer (score 1):

For me Themes are very powerful to keep control on consistent look and feel, loading of frameworks.
In your themes you have also direct access to the managed beans, when they are available.
On my first encounter of themes I also was wondering why I should use it. But know it my starting point of my XPages app.

Comment: Consistent look and feel i also have with CSS. Can you please give me an example why i want to use a managed bean with themes?

Answer (score 0):

CSS allows you to use an alias to map to what you would otherwise put in the **style** property of a control.

A themeId is similar, in allowing you to use an alias to map to what you would otherwise put in style property of a control **but also most other properties**.

Adding a control reference to the default themeId of a control (which you can check by using the SSJS `getComponent("myComp").getStyleKitFamily()`) allows you to default or override settings for most of those properties.

The benefit comes also when computing properties. By default during a partial refresh those calculations will get recomputed many times, to take into account changes made during each of the JSF lifecycle phases. However, all property calculations in a theme are only computed during the render response phase, so there can be a performance benefit.

A theme can also be placed on the server, so you're further minimising the duplication of effort.